# I want to know the meaning of 而 which is used inside 公司一再宽容,而他却越来越过分了。

Tags: grammar

> 公司一再宽容,而他却越来越过分了。

**My free translation:** *The company has  tolerated him again and again, and he has been getting worse and worse.*

I've interpreted the 而 as "but" however seems 却 also has the meaning "but".

What does this 而 actually mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

而 here should be [然而](https://cantoneseplus.com/word/10670) (however/ but)

公司一再宽容, (**然而**)他(**却**)越来越过分了 = The company has been tolerant repeatedly, (**however**), he has gone too far. (*meaning the company will no longer be tolerant of him*)

> 却 also has the meaning "but".

[然而]他[却] = [可是/ 但是]他[却] = [however/ but], he

Answer (score 2):

The form "**而 ... 却**" is used for turning/transiting the direction of two opposite events/things from one to another.

- "公司一再宽容, **而**他**却**越来越过分了" - "...., **but/however (on the contrary)**....". (Here, the transition occurs between the two opposite attitudes - 宽容 and 过分)

Answer (score 1):

"**而 ... 却**" = "**而**" = "**却**" = "**但是**" = "**反而**" = "**倒**" = "**倒是**"

They all mean but, however, whereas, nevertheless, nonetheless, still, yet, though, although, even so, etc.

For example:

(1) 公司一再宽容, **而**他**却**越来越过分了.

(2) 公司一再宽容, **而**他越来越过分了.

(3) 公司一再宽容, 他**却**越来越过分了.

(4) 公司一再宽容, **但是**他越来越过分了.

(5) 公司一再宽容, 他**反而**越来越过分了.

(6) 公司一再宽容, 他**倒**越来越过分了.

(7) 公司一再宽容, 他**倒是**越来越过分了.

Those sentences have almost the same meanings.

In your translation, "**and**" is not correct.

The company has tolerated him again and again, **and** (X) he has been getting worse and worse.

Answer (score 0):

I would not solely concentrate on 而=然而. Like you say, what is 却 in that case? Don't they work together, as r13 says?

她顺利通过了考试，而他却奋力挣扎。
While she sailed through her exams, he struggled.

而他却假装没看到，飞快地骑走了。
Instead of stopping, he pretended not to see this and rode away quickly.

然而自1796年来，贝多芬开始逐渐丧失听力，而他却无视疾病的折磨，潜心音乐，并不断创作出伟大的作品。
In the year 1796 Beethoven began losing his hearing. In spite of his illness he immersed himself in his work and created some of the greatest works of music.

公司一再宽容,而他却越来越过分了。
The company has been repeatedly tolerant, and he just got more and more lax.

却:
(3) 还 [still]。

如:却是(还是)

(4) 才 [just]。

如:却才(方才)

(5) 恰;正 [just]。